# For which intervals $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the intersection $[a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ a clopen subset of the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For which intervals $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the intersection $[a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ a clopen subset of the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$?

Can someone give me a hint on how to start?

Comment: **Hint:** A subset $S$ of $\Bbb Q$ is open (resp. closed) if and only if there is an open (resp. closed) subset $U$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $S=U\cap\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $[a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not open.